# Combining different parser rules to simplify processing within TreeListener in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

This is a portion of my grammar file:

```
paragraph
    : TEXT? italic TEXT?
    | TEXT? STAR TEXT?
    | TEXT? labelRef TEXT?
    | TEXT? BRACE_OPEN TEXT?
    | TEXT? LABEL TEXT?
    | ELEMENTPATH
    | TEXT
    ;
```

The paragraph rule should "mark" all paragraphs within my island grammar because I want to generate p blocks around the generated paragraph elements. Technically all different paragraph elements are recognized.

The problem is, that the different rules lead to different paragraph calls within my listener. That's completely logic due to the different rules but it makes processing the tree within the listener very hard. The two different entries (as an example) for the same paragraph can be found in image 1.

[image]

The input text is:

```
Text text paragraph 1 text *italic* text and here the same paragraph with a * but a different entry in the tree.
```

Just one paragraph but if I process the tree the output HTML would contain two paragraphs.

Is there a way to combine those different rule portions into one paragraph call? There shouldn't be two different paragraphs within the parse tree if just one paragraph is meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `paragraph` rule is set up to recognize only a single defined string at a time. So, your first paragraph is `TEXT italic TEXT` and the second `STAR TEXT`.

Try

```
paragraph 
    : ( TEXT? italic TEXT?
      | TEXT? STAR TEXT?
      | TEXT? labelRef TEXT?
      | TEXT? BRACE_OPEN TEXT?
      | TEXT? LABEL TEXT?
      | ELEMENTPATH
      | TEXT
      )+
    ;
```

Comment: Oh of course! Haven't thought about this. Works perfectly well. Thanks a lot!